# Customer Portal...Custom Report header is not translated at the time of downloading

Tags: customer-portal, customization

Here I am Login with Chineses Language in Customer Portal, there are one custom reports and i want to download from Export Detail buttons....when i download as excel or csv format heading is not showing in Chineses language(Instead of ???? is displied) downloaded file(Excel).

Except Ciineses language there is no issue in other language...

Here i translate following 3 places

1. Workbench Translation
2. Custom Label
3. Rename tab

How can i solve this issue....means is it a standard functionality where can i find...this type of translation....

I am Pretty new in customization so please help me to solve this Bug..

Comment: Hello Please it is Urgent help to find out solutions.....

Comment: i think  ISO-8859-1 is not supported chinese language......